# RegEx, characters between 2 strings without positive lookbehind

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a sentence like this `Give me 4 of ABCD_X and then do something`

I need to extract `ABCD_X` - any set of characters after `Give me 4 of`  and before space.
Number can be any size

I am able to do it with this expression (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings) question):

`(?<=^Give me \d of )(.*?)(?=\s)`
But the number can be 10 or greater, so
`(?<=^Give me \d+ of )(.*?)(?=\s)` returns error in python (pandas column) that positive lookbehind should be fixed width.

Is there a way to avoid positive lookbehind to exract those characters?

Comment: Try capping the number of digits, e.g. `\d{1,15}`

Comment: Instead of a lookbehind, you could just use a non-capturing group ```(?:^Give me...)```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
^Give me \d+ of (\S+)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ibyhA1/1)

---

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `Give me \d+ of`  - Literally your searchstring with 1+ digits.
- `(\S+)` - A capture group with 1+ non-whitespace characters.

---

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Series(['Give me 4 of ABCD_X and then do something', 'Give me 10 of ABCD_Y and then do something'])
df = df.str.extract(r'^Give me \d+ of (\S+)')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   0
0  ABCD_X
1  ABCD_Y
```

**Note:** If you would use a named capture group, the column header will use the name of that group instead of the integer of the group.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a lot! Especially for the detailed explanation and testing it on pandas!