# is there a regex expression to replace this if condition

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements, indexof

I have three string and i need to check if one of them contains the other 2 in the same order given, right now i am using alot of conditions to achive this, is there a way to simplify it using regex?

here is the code:

```
var a = '**';
var b = '##';
var phrase = '**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet##';

if(phrase.includes(a) && phrase.includes(b) && (phrase.indexOf(a) < phrase.indexOf(b))) {
  // add logic
}
```

Comment: Please may you share regexes you have tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

Comment: @RobertHarvey That duplicate will not answer the question.

Comment: I don't even know what the question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pattern to match ** before ##

```
^(?:(?!##|\*\*).)*\*\*.*##
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:(?!##|\*\*).)*` Match any char while not directly followed by either `##` or `**`
- `\*\*` First match `**`
- `.*` Match any character 0+ times
- `##` Match `##`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9zkNkR/1)

```
var phrase = '**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet##';

if (phrase.match(/^(?:(?!##|\*\*).)*\*\*.*##/)) {
  // add logic
}
```

```js
var phrases = [
  '**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet##',
  'test****#**##',
  '##**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet##',
  '##**##**',
];
phrases.forEach(phrase => {
  if (phrase.match(/^(?:(?!##|\*\*).)*\*\*.*##/)) {
    console.log(`Match for ${phrase}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`No match for ${phrase}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: What about something simpler `/\*\*.+?##/`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because that something simpler gives a false positive here https://regex101.com/r/IO4n0u/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks thats what i was looking for