# regex extract all characters between a start and end string

Tags: regex, re2

I have strings that looks like this.

```
setting-bs_b77f423715d2b991-node
setting-bs_b77f423715d2b991-eggs
setting-bs_b77f423715d2b991-cheese
setting-bs_b14835f519bf447d-ham
```

How do I extract just the middle element? e.g. `bs_b14835f519bf447d`it is always the same length and always has the same `bs_` prefix.

I unfortunately cannot use a lookbehind for this problem, as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings) as the regex must run inside bigquery which does not support lookbehinds

Comment: Just use a capturing group, `r"bs_(\w+)"`

Comment: Assuming you have no other 16-char alphanumeric words then `[a-z0-9]{16}` could work. https://regex101.com/r/6vhSH6/1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thank you, that appeared to work correctly. If you answer I can mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have no other 16-char alphanumeric words then `[a-z0-9]{16}` could work.

https://regex101.com/r/6vhSH6/1