# What is the regex to match anything between two words?

Tags: regex

Regex Equivalent of "`word1ASTERISKword2`", where `word1` is the start of a sentence, `word2` is the end of the sentence, I use this "`word1ASTERISKword2`" in MS Excel.

I want to know that is the regex match to this?. I have already tried `^word1(.*)word2$`. Not working.

Comment: Maybe this would help: [Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what "*Not working*" means.

Comment: You could use some looking around. `(?<=` looks behind and `(?=` looks ahead. `(?<=word1).*(?=word2)`