# Regex match optional string greedy inbetween two random strings

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a way to match an optional `ABC` in the following strings.
Both strings should be matched either way, if `ABC` is there or not:

precedingstringwithundefinedlenght**ABC**subsequentstringwithundefinedlength
precedingstringwithundefinedlenghtsubsequentstringwithundefinedlength

I've tried

```
.*(ABC).*
```

which doesn't work for an optional `ABC` but making `ABC` non greedy doesn't work either as the `.*` will take all the pride:

```
.*(ABC)?.*
```

This is NOT a duplicate to e.g. [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings) as I am looking for a certain string inbetween two random string,  kind of the other way around.

Comment: so it should match if `ABC` is there or if it is not there? that means it should always match ?!?

Comment: @user16320675 Well in my case I have to use Regex. Otherwise there are obviously better methods.

Comment: @user16320675 exactly, it should always match, but I want the ABC grouped if it’s there.

Comment: @user16320675 Yes it is. I didn’t ask for a Java way to do it but for a regular expression. I have included example code that makes it clear that I want to group the match. Read again.

Comment: I have included two regex examples. And I have intentionally included the Java tag because my regex runs on a Java machine. I am not able to change the code. I didn’t ask for a way to use a Java function, did I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
.*(ABC).*|.*
```

This works like this:

- `.*(ABC).*` pattern is searched for first, since it is the leftmost part of an alternation (see ["Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager)), it looks for any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, then captures `ABC` into Group 1 and then matches the rest of the line with the right-hand `.*`
- `|` - or
- `.*` - is searched for if the first alternation part does not match.

**Another solution without the need to use alternation**:

```
^(?:.*(ABC))?.*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x30omU/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*(ABC))?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then captures into Group 1 an `ABC` char sequence
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Comment: Eventually the same as my solution but much cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: @dmuensterer Yes, I enhanced your pattern (I wanted to explain why this approach works) and suggested another pattern without alternation, too.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve come up with an answer myself:
Using the OR operator seems to work:

```
(?:(?:.*(ABC))|.*).*
```

If there’s a better way, feel free to answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score -4):

You could use this regex: `.*(ABC){0,1}.*`. It means any, optional{min,max}, any. It is easier to read. I can' t say if your solution or mine is faster due to the processing speed.
Options:
`{value}` = n-times
`{min,}` = min to infinity
`{min,max}` = min to max

Comment: There is no difference between `{0,1}` and `?`, so it doesn’t solve the OP’s problem at all.

Comment: If you write `{min,}` the range is min- infinity

Comment: `.*(ABC){0,1}.*` is not helpful, it is the same as `.*` and matches any string. It is because the first `.*` grabs the whole string and then `(ABC){0,1}` matches an empty string at the end of string, and the match is returned.

Answer (score -4):

`.+([ABC])?.+` should do the job

Comment: try it first....

Comment: `.*([ABC])?.*` is not helpful, it is the same as `.*` and matches any string. It is because the first `.*` grabs the whole string and then `([ABC])?` matches an empty string at the end of string, and the match is returned.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/zxtdoM/1

Comment: @noah Right, you can see `ABC` is not captured, not highlighted, at https://regex101.com/r/zxtdoM/1.

Comment: @wiktor afaik it's in capture group 1, should be able to access that

Comment: Yes, but Group 1 value is an empty string here. That is the problem and I explained why it is like this in my comment above.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew even worse, `[ABC]` can never match `ABC` *in general*.

Comment: @Holger In light of how the regex works, it is not even important what is inside Group 1 since the regex engine never consumes the text Group 1 pattern is supposed to match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it’s indeed not important to the result (though it highlights even more that this answer could have suggested to just use `.*` to the same result). But it’s important in that this answerer changed `ABC` to `[ABC]` a) for no reason and b) apparently without understanding the meaning of the regex constructs.