# Regular expression to extract Hyphenated text including other special characters between multiple hyphens

Tags: regex, pyspark

I have a cases where I need to extract anything in between multiple hyphens together.
For example

```
------- General Data ------------------------------------------------------------
O/p: General Data

------- Protocol and Sequence Data ----------------------------------------------

O/p: Protocol and Sequence Data

------- Start Check Data - (before measurement - may be cached data) ------------

o/p: Start Check Data - (before measurement - may be cached data)
```

I have used this particular regex to try and achieve it

```
(?<=-)[^-]+(?=)
```

but this regex is able to get the first 2 cases correctly but not the 3rd case example.
It matches the 3rd case but it only displays, for example for

```
------- Start Check Data - (before measurement - may be cached data) ------------
it gives o/p Start Check Data instead of the whole thing
```

Comment: Possible duplicate (a better suggestion is welcomed): [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6109882). TLDR: [`^-+\s*(.+?)\s*-+$`](https://regex101.com/r/4R0dO3/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a space will always appear before and after a series of hyphens and dealing with the match's length of a lookbehind that must be fixed, here is a possible regex:

```
(?<=-- ).+(?= -{2,})
```

lookbehind for 2 hyphens and a space :

```
(?<=-- )
```

match everything in a greedy way :

```
.+
```

(switch to lazy match if needed by adding a '?') :

```
.+?
```

lookahead for a space followed by at least 2 hyphens :

```
(?= -{2,})
```