# How do I use regex in JavaScript to capture the text between two particular characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

In the example below I am trying to capture the text between the two asterixes.

```
var str="The *rain in SPAIN* stays mainly in the plain"; 
var patt1=/\*...\*/;
console.log(str.match(patt1));
```

I'm trying to follow the example here

http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

> \Q...\E   Matches the characters between \Q and \E literally,
>   suppressing the meaning of special characters.

But I am having trouble following along

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters, while EXCLUDING the delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var str="The *rain in SPAIN* stays mainly in the plain"; 
var patt1=/\*.*\*/;
console.log(str.match(patt1));
```

The `\*` means the literal "*" character. Then the `.` means any character and `*` means any number of times, so `.*` means "any number of characters".

---

Optional bonus:

The code above should work fine, but you'll notice that it matches greedily. So with input  `abcd*efgh*ijkl*mnop`, the output will be `*efgh*ijkl*`, whereas you might have preferred the non-greedy match `*efgh*`.

To do this, use

```
var patt1=/\*.*?\*/;
```

The `?` operator indicates non-greediness and ensures the least number of characters possible to get to the next `\*` are eaten, whereas without the `?`, the most characters possible to get to the next `\*` are eaten.

To learn more I recommend http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html . In particular read the "laziness instead of greediness" part.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.*` and `()` to capture groups:

```
var str = "The *rain in SPAIN* stays mainly* in the plain"; 
var patt1 = /\*(.*)\*/;

console.log(str.match(patt1));
```

And the result:

```
["*rain in SPAIN* in the plain*", "rain in SPAIN* in the plain"]
```

---

If you use:

```
var patt1=/\*([^*]+)\*/;
```

the result will be:

```
["*rain in SPAIN*", "rain in SPAIN"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the three dots? `...`

```
var str="The *rain in SPAIN* stays mainly in the plain"; 
var patt1=/\*.*\*/;
console.log(str.match(patt1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're seeing the ... in the example.
a . is a single instance of any char (a wild card.
So, in your example what you would need to do is this...

```
var patt1=/\*.*?\*/;
```

However you're going to get the * on both sides as part of your result.

You're searching for an actual *

then you're searching for any number of . (wild cards)... any number because * also means as many as you find

but the ? means that you should stop if you encounter the next thing

which in  your case is a litteral * again.

so... 
to translate

ASTERISK(anything as many times at it happens until another)ASTERISK