# RegEx to get text from inside the square brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters, while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclu)

I have a function where I have to get text which is enclosed in square brackets but not brackets for example

```
this is [test] line i [want] text [inside] square [brackets]
```

from the above line I want words:

```
test
want
inside
brackets
```

I am trying with to do this with `/\[(.*?)\]/g` but I am not getting satisfied result, I get the words inside brackets but also brackets which are not what I want

I did search for some similar type of question on SO but none of those solution  work properly for me here is one what found `(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])` this works in RegEx coach but not with JavaScript. Here is [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets) from where I got this

here is what I have done so far: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5SNLM/)

please help.

Comment: its not exact duplicate square bracket in not a normal character it has to be dealt differently then other characters

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A single lookahead should do the trick here:

```
 a = "this is [test] line i [want] text [inside] square [brackets]"
 words = a.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)
```

but in a general case, `exec` or `replace`-based loops lead to simpler code:

```
words = []
a.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, function($0, $1) { words.push($1) })
```

Comment: Could the look ahead regex not be simplified? /[^\[\]]+(?=\])/g

Answer (score 6):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SNLM/2/) uses [RegExp.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and outputs only what's inside the parenthesis.

```
var data = "this is [test] line i [want] text [inside] square [brackets]"
var re= /\[(.*?)\]/g;
for(m = re.exec(data); m; m = re.exec(data)){
    alert(m[1])
}
```

Comment: Sir can you please explain me what is happening in for loop and can we use underscore.js 's _each() function to iterate