# Finding the content between two characters regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a `.txt` file that contains all the info of a particular item on each line, in this format:

```
1 +'item 1'+ [0, 0]
2 +'item 2'+ [0, 0]
```

The first number is the item id, the string between the `+` signs is the item name, and the list at the end is the stats of the item. I need to use regex to get the name between the `+` symbols, but all of the answers I find aren't exactly what I'm looking for, and I don't understand regex very well at all. What pattern should I use to find the name?

Similar questions/answers, that don't really answer my question: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013110/regex-to-get-text-from-inside-the-square-brackets?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: If you can show us what you've tried so far, it is often easier to improve on your attempt than for us to start from scratch. Also, I often end up finding my own answer when I try to write up what I've already attempted.

Comment: What about `"1 +'item 1'+ [0, 0]".split('+')[1]` instead of regex ?

Comment: How's `"(?<=')[^']+?(?=')"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to isolate the item name using regular string methods, see below.

```py
saved_names = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fr:
    for line in fr.readlines():
        name = line.split('+')[1]
        saved_names.append(name)
```

Or use regex:

```py
# compile pattern, catch all items.
pattern = re.compile(r'(.+)\s\+(.+)\+\s(.+)')

saved = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fr:
    for line in fr.readlines():
        name = match(pattern, line.strip('\n'))
        id, name, data = matches.groups()
        saved.append((id, name, data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use split method but if you really need to use regex, you can do it like this:

```
import re

file = 'filepath/to/your/text/file.txt'

with open(file, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    pattern = r'\'(.+)\''
    solution = re.findall(pattern, f.read())

print(solution)
```