# Using regular expressions, cut the text and move it to the second <textarea>

Tags: javascript, jquery

If `[media=*]` is in the first `textarea` then bring it to the second `textarea` and remove from the first.

What I start with:

```html
<textarea style="width:400px;height:100px;" class="test_3">The classification of passenger cars as a class of wheeled vehicles, and within this class, in itself is quite conditional: some cars may be "transitional".
    
[media=https://youtu.be/JArIzszDb6Y]
[media=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JArIzszDb6Y]
    
The classification of passenger cars.
</textarea>

<textarea style="width:400px;height:100px;" id="test_4"></textarea>
```

What I want to get to:

```html
<textarea style="width:400px;height:100px;" class="test_3">The classification of passenger cars as a class of wheeled vehicles, and within this class, in itself is quite conditional: some cars may be "transitional".
    
    
The classification of passenger cars.
</textarea>
    
<textarea style="width:400px;height:100px;" id="test_4">   
[media=https://youtu.be/JArIzszDb6Y]
[media=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JArIzszDb6Y]
</textarea>
```

Comment: This can move you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013110/regex-to-get-text-from-inside-the-square-brackets

Comment: There are no problems with the regular expression /\[media=(.+)\]/g

Answer (score 0):

```js
function transferMedia() {
  var text = $('[id="test_3"]').val();

  if (/\[media=(.+)\]/g.test(text)) {
    var media = text.match(/\[media=(.+)\]/g);
    $('[id="test_4"]').val(media);
  }

  var txt = $('[id="test_3"]'), val = txt.val();
  val = val.replace(/\n*\[media=(.+)\]\n*/g, '\u000A');
  txt.val(val);
            
  remove_n();
}

function remove_n() {
  var txt = $('[id="test_3"]'), val = txt.val();
  val = val.replace(/[ \n]+$/g, '');
  txt.val(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="width:400px;height:100px;" id="test_3">
  The classification of passenger cars as a class of wheeled vehicles, and within this class, in itself is quite conditional: some cars may be "transitional".
    
  [media=https://youtu.be/JArIzszDb6Y]
  [media=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JArIzszDb6Y]
    
  The classification of passenger cars.
</textarea>

<textarea style="width:400px;height:100px;" id="test_4"></textarea>

<input type="button" onclick="transferMedia()" value="click">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.