# NSString replace regex

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have a string like this:

```
NSString* msg = @"Hello this is a new message to @[123:Dr Zoidberg] and his nippers";
```

And I want to use `-stringByReplacingMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:` to convert this pattern to:

```
NSString* msg = @"Hello this is a new message to Dr Zoidberg and his nippers";
```

This is what I have so far:

```
NSString* msg = @"Hello this is a new message to @[123:Dr Zoidberg] and his nippers";
NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: @"????"
                                                                       options: NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error: nil];

NSString* plainText = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString: msg
                                                      options: 0
                                                        range: NSMakeRange(0, [msg length])
                                                 withTemplate: @"$2"];
```

Can anyone help me with the @"????" pattern?

Comment: What is the template format? In `@[123:Dr Zoidberg]`, what can replace the `123` number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the pattern I was after: `@(.*?):(.*?)]`. Thanks go to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclu).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
@\[\d+:(.+?)\]
```

with the `\1` group

Explanation:

Match `@` followed by `[`, then any number of digits followed by a comma. From this point get the text until you find the closing square bracket.

If there can be any kind of whitespace between the digits and the `:` you can use this one

```
@\[\d+\t*:(.+?)\]
```

Comment: It works on notepad++. What does it match / doesn't it match? It looks a lot like the one mmdemirbas commented, maybe the problem is the square bracket at the beginning

Comment: Uhu, can there be a space (or any indentation character) between `123` and `:`? if so you can write it in this fashion `@\[\d+\t+?:(.+?)\]`

Comment: the `?` means "don't be greedy with the +", in this case in fact you can omit it (my mistake, I'll edit the answer)

Comment: Think I understood: you must replace `withTemplate: @"$2"` with `withTemplate: @"$1"` telling to use the first replacing group, not the second

Answer (score 0):

Search for `@\[123:(.*?)\]` and replace with `\1`