# Regexp to capture string between delimiters

Tags: regex

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclu/1454936#comment21122977_1454936) question a regex for capturing a string between delimiters is provided:

**Test:** `This is a test string [more or less]`

**Regexp:** `(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])`

**Returns:** `more or less`

What if the string to be captured also contains delimiters?

**Test 1:** `This is a test string [more [or] less]`

**Return 1:** `more [or] less`

**Test 2:** `This is a test string [more [or [and] or] less]`

**Return 2:** `more [or [and] or] less`

And multiple brackets?

**Test 3:** `This is a test string [more [or [and] or] less] and [less [or [and] or] more]`

**Return 3:** `more [or [and] or] less`, `less [or [and] or] more`

Which regex would do this? Or which small ruby/python script can do this?

Comment: You are trying to tell regex to track when the bracket is "closed". I don't think it can do that.

Comment: Indeed. I asked it as a comment there but I guess it deserves a separate question.

Comment: I would rather write a custom function, to count number of open brackets until it's closed (shifting index forward). But I wish I see the regexp here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In javascript

```
var str = 'This is a test string [more [or [and] or] less]';    
str = str.match( /\[(.+)\]/ )[1];
// "more [or [and] or] less"
```

If you omit the `?`, the `.+` will match greedily up to the last `]`.

In python

```
str = "This is a test string [more [or [and] or] less]"
re.search( "(?<=\[).+(?=\])", str ).group()
// "more [or [and] or] less"
```

**Update** for multiple nested brackets

In javascript

```
var matches = [],
    str = 'This is a test string [more [or [and] or] less] and [less [or [and] or] more] and [more]';

str.replace( /\[([^\]]*\[?[^\]]*\]?[^[]*)\]/g, function ( $0, $1 ) {
    $1 && matches.push( $1 );
});

console.log( matches );
// [ "more [or [and] or] less", "less [or [and] or] more", "more" ]
```

In python

```
import re
str = 'This is a test string [more [or [and] or] less] and [less [or [and] or] more] and [more]'

matches = re.findall( r'\[([^\]]*\[?[^\]]*\]?[^[]*)\]', str )

print matches
# [ 'more [or [and] or] less', 'less [or [and] or] more', 'more' ]
```

Comment: Nice, how would you deal with the multiple set of nested brackets case?

Comment: The regex solution will fail badly with `[[]] [[]]`

Comment: @gnzlbg. Updated to handle multiple nested in python.