# Regex capture string between delimiters and excluding them

Tags: html, node.js, regex, string, match

I saw in this forum an answare close to my "request" but not enough
([Regexp to capture string between delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031253/regexp-to-capture-string-between-delimiters)).

My question is: I have an HTML page and I would get only the src of all "img" tags of this page and put them in one array without using cheerio (I'm using node js).

The problem is that i would prefer to exclude the delimiters.
How could i resolve this problem?

Comment: Why do you not want to use cheerio?

Comment: In most environments you would simply put the delimiters inside [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) – lookahead `(?=)` for the ending delimiter and lookbehind `(?<=)` for the starting delimiter. However, JavaScript does not support lookbehind, so you will need a workaround, such as [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Really appreciate your support.

Comment: For now i'm using this:
var images  = data.match(/src="(.*).jpg"/g);

Comment: If anybody want to know what i'm trying to do and want to help me in this project can contact me on skype

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible with regex, but it would be much easier (and probably faster but don't quote me on that) to use a native DOM method. Let's start with the regex approach. We can use a capture group to easily parse the `src` of an `img` tag:

```js
var html = `test<div>hello</div>
<img src="first">
<img class="test" src="second" data-lang="en">
test
<img src="third" >`;
var srcs = [];
html.replace(/<img[^<>]*src=['"](.*?)['"][^<>]*>/gm, (m, $1) => { srcs.push($1) })

console.log(srcs);
```

However, the better way would be to use `getElementsByTagName`:
(note the following will get some kind of parent domain url since the srcs are relative/fake but you get the idea)

```js
var srcs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img')).map(img => img.src);

console.log(srcs);
```

```html
test<div>hello</div>
<img src="first">
<img class="test" src="second" data-lang="en">
test
<img src="third" >
```

Comment: Ty very much at all. I'm not using cheerio because i think it's much slower. I get an HTML page with request module then i just want to extract all the src of every images.