# the best way for character replacement in String in java

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to check a string  for each character I replace it with other characters or keep it in the string. and also because it's a long string the time to do this task is so important. what is the best way of these, or any better idea?
for all of them I append the result to an StringBuilder.
check all of the characters with a for and charAt commands.
use switch like the previous way.
use replaceAll twice.

and if one of the first to methods is better is there any way to check a character with a group of characters, like :
if (st.charAt(i)=='a'..'z') ....

Edit:
please tell the less consuming in time way and tell the reason.I know all of these ways you said!

Comment: EDIT: title =~ s/reolacement/replacement/    =)

Comment: Is this all your program does, or just a part of it? In Unix, you can simply use the `tr` command for that.

Comment: it's just a part and the time is so important because the size of the String is too big.

Comment: Is this String in a file?

Comment: yes. I read it part by part and replace unwanted characters and do some other things and prepare it to be a dictionary.

Comment: As mentioned before, why don't you use `tr` ?

Comment: I don't know about it. is it usable in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace a single character (or a single sequence), use `replace()`, as other answers have suggested.

If you want to replace several characters (e.g., `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`) with a single substitute character or character sequence (e.g., "X"), you should use a regular expression replace:

```
String result = original.replaceAll("[abc]", "X");
```

If you want to replace several characters, each with a different replacement (e.g., `'a'` with `'A'`, `'b'` with `'B'`), then looping through the string yourself and building the result in a `StringBuilder` will probably be the most efficient. This is because, as you point out in your question, you will be going through the string only once.

```
String sb = new StringBuilder();
String targets = "abc";
String replacements = "ABC";
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
    char c = original.charAt(i);
    int loc = targets.indexOf(c);
    sb.append(loc >= 0 ? replacements.charAt(loc) : c);
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and find some good methods:

```
char from = 'a';
char to = 'b';
str = str.replace(from, to);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String replaceSample = "This String replace Example shows 
how to replace one char from String";
String newString = replaceSample.replace('r', 't');
```

**Output: This Stting teplace Example shows how to teplace one chat ftom Stting**

Also, you could use contains:

```
 str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase())
```

To check if the substring str2 exists in str1

Edit.

Just read that the String come from a file. You can use Regex for this. That would be the best method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html

Comment: read the question once again. I know all of the ways but looking for the best one!

Comment: Okay, this is the best one. 0: )

Comment: better than surveying the String char by char?why?

Comment: Because if you have an API, and you do for this, it's always a better idea to use it than to create a new method by yourself. Don't make what it's already made. And if it's made by the guys that create and maintain Java, trust in their methods.

Comment: what if I have to use it twice and it surveys my long String twice, but if I write it just one time I survey.

Comment: Could you explain yourself a little "deeper" please.

Comment: I want to replace all of the uppercases to lower cases and replace all of the characters except a-z  with space.Is it enough?

Comment: With Regex you can find substring parseing the file in the best possible computing time. Then you can replace the substrings with the code I gave you. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclu

Answer (score 1):

This is your comment:

> I want to replace all of the uppercases to lower cases and replace all
>   of the characters except a-z with space.

You can do it like this:

```
str = str.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", " ");
```

Your requirement should be part of the question, not in comment #7 under a posted answer...

Comment: this is not my question. my important question is the best way! i mentioned all of these ways in the question and asked the best one:
"what is the best way of these, or any better idea? for all of them I append the result to an StringBuilder. 
check all of the characters with a for and charAt commands.
 use switch like the previous way. 
use replaceAll twice."

Comment: @user2273552: Are you using a profiler? Is this part of the code your bottleneck? I'd say it won't get any faster than the code I posted. I bet you lose much more time for I/O than the string manipulation. Also, what is a long string in your case? Length a million, billion, trillion, longer??

Comment: yes. surely other part consume time more but I want to decreas this part too.it's a 1.5G .txt file that I read part by part and so on.
thanx any how

Comment: @Paniz: Does this have to be done in java? this can be done in one line in a shell, and it'll be ultra-fast.

Comment: it's a part of a big program. how should I concat them if write to different palces?

Comment: with the `cat` command. Seems to me your program can be replaced by a few line short shell script and be much much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) for Java. You can match an entire set of characters. Strings have several functions: `replace`, `replaceAll`, and `match`, which you may find useful here.

You can match the set of alphanumeric, for instance, using `[a-zA-Z]`, which may be what you're looking for.