# Regular Expression to retrieve strings between two pairs of braces

Tags: regex

I need regular expression that will retrieve strings between two pairs of {{ }}, non gridy, ignoring few special characters. For example :

The text: 
**{{Lorem ((ipsum dolor [[sit amet]], consectetur)) adipiscing}}{{elit. ((Proin eget [[felis sit]] amet)) diam}}**

Target:
Will Match the following 2 matches:

1. **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing**
2. **elit. Proin eget felis sit amet diam**

All the match should be without the partenless, brackets and the braces

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclu it may help you

Comment: you can match using this pattern "{{[^}]*}}" then replace that few special characters with empty character

Comment: This can't be done in a single regex if the same type of braces can be nested indefinitely. What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using .NET, thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the match should be without the partenless, brackets and the
>   braces

Matches are substrings of the original string, you cannot have gaps in them, so what you're asking for is impossible.

You can match for the whole string, then filter out the unneeded characters in your favorite programming language...

```
{{.*?}}
```

Comment: @WesleyBaugh: Dear downvoter, no, you BSing... :/ lookahead/behind is possible for the {{ }} but not for the other braces. And the capabilities of regexes are quite limited, not only by your imagination...

Comment: lol. I'm waiting for your impossible answer that solves his problem. cheers.