# Get String with Specific Tags in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I'm looking for a way to get strings from a string with specific tags, e.g.
I have this string: `"Hello <date> My <name> is <your name>"`
I  need to return this:
`<date>`
`<name>`
`<your name>`

in an array or a list

only words starts and ends with <>.

Thanks a million! :-)

Comment: How do the input and output correlate? I can't tell what you're doing to get between them. Ah, your edit cleared it up.

Comment: Can you please post a full sample? It's not clear what's your input, output and what have you tried.

Comment: What have you tried? What options have you considered? We are not a place that hands out code to people who show us no effort.

Comment: Did you think to look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Regex pattern `<.*?>` to retrieve each word, ie

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, "<.*?>");
```

You can then iterate over the collection to get the tags.

Comment: Better, IMO, than looking for characters that aren't `<>` is to make the `*` not greedy: `"<.*?>"`.

Comment: Actually, for a long time non-greedy syntax in regex was iffy on browser support, but testing it it appears that's no longer relevant with current browsers.

Comment: fantastic answer thank you saved me a life time of trouble. Trying to locate specific html tags inside JSON strings. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Mike Precup beat me by 1 minute :) anyway you should use [Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclu), e.g.:

```
var s = @"some <thing> is different <about> this <string>";
var pattern = @"(?<=\<)(.*?)(?=\>)";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var matches = regex.Matches(s);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    match.Groups[0].Captures[0].Value.Dump(); // using LINQPad
}
```

and the output is:

```
thing
about
string
```

Kind regards,
P.

Comment: Yes, This code works like a charm! easy, fast, great. Thanks a million!