# Get String with Specific Tags in VB

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

I have already seen this thread - [Get String with Specific Tags in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637664/get-string-with-specific-tags-in-c-sharp/30197377)

I'm looking for the same to get strings from a string with specific tags, but my tags are in the following format:

```
[BROWSERLINK]
[REMOVE]
[CURRENT_YEAR]
[SITEURL]
[EMAIL]
```

If I change the regex simply replacing `<>` with `[]` it fails telling me:

```
parsing "(?[=\[)(.*?)(?=\])" - Unterminated [] set.
```

I can't change my tags to `<>` as the string also contains HTML tags that I don't want touched, any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` and `]` are considered [special characters in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html). You need to escape them to match as literals:

```
Dim pattern As String = "(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])"
```

This should work for you, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5c%5b)(.*%3f)(%3f%3d%5c%5d)&i=%5bBROWSERLINK%5d%0d%0a%5bREMOVE%5d%0d%0a%5bCURRENT_YEAR%5d%0d%0a%5bSITEURL%5d%0d%0a%5bEMAIL%5d).

Your regex - `(?[=[)(.*?)(?=])` - has another issue, too: the `[` after `(?` which ruined the positive look-behind structure. As you see, the `?[` is replaced with `(?<` in my suggested regex. A correct positive [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) looks like `(?<=...)`.