# Regex to Replace Ruby Exception Handlers

Tags: ruby, regex, rubymine

I'm trying to find and replace all instances of exception handling for standard errors, e.g.:

```
begin
  ...
rescue StandardError => e
  logger.debug e.to_s
end
```

The answer here sounds like it should do what I want:

[Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclu)

It led me to the following two possible regexes:

```
begin(.*?)rescue
(?<=begin)(.*?)(?=rescue)
```

Neither of these match anything.  I'm not sure whether the problem is with the regexes or the IDE (Rubymine).

Suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

. does not match newline by default.

Prepend `(?s)` or `(?sm)` in your regular expression to make dot(.) match newline.
Or add `s` or `sm` switch.

```
?> "begin statements... rescue".scan /begin(.*?)rescue/
=> [[" statements... "]]
>> "begin statements...\n rescue".scan /begin(.*?)rescue/
=> []
>> "begin statements...\n rescue".scan /begin(.*?)rescue/s
=> []
>> "begin statements...\n rescue".scan /begin(.*?)rescue/sm
=> [[" statements...\n "]]
```