# Regex matching wrong pattern

Tags: c#, regex, powershell

I'm trying to pull text out of a word document using regex look ahead and look behind foudn in this answer:

[Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclu)

The delimeters I have to work with are

Start: `RQ`

End: `END-RQ`

I have added the following (powershell) code:

```
$regex = [regex] '(?<=RQ)(.*?)(?=END-RQ)' 

$matches = $regex.Matches($concat)
```

The problem is the matching is grabbing the RQ from END-RQ as the beginning of the next pattern. Can anyone tell me how to eliminate that (e.g. force the regex to match exactly RQ and END-RQ)? Wrapping the matching patterns in quotes does not seem to work, even when the quotes are escaped.

Comment: in this particular case and assuming that all your "RQ...END-RQ" are balanced, isn't it more simple (and probably faster) to use: `RQ((?>[^E]+|E(?!ND-RQ))*)END-RQ` and then extract the capturing group (since you use a capturing group)?

Comment: The groups are gauraunteed to be balanced. Thanks for pointing this out though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$regex = [regex] '(?<=(?<!END-)RQ)(.*?)(?=END-RQ)'
```

Answer (score 0):

you should download this application:

http://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/Details/12425

it is priceless when trying to debug regex.

Comment: Awesome. I can't wait to try this! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

This might work (hard to say without knowing exactly what your data is):

```
$regex = [regex]'(?<=(?:^|[^-])RQ)(.*?)(?=END-RQ)'
```