# regex match till a character from a second occurance of a different character

Tags: regex

My question is pretty similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclu) and the answer is almost fine. Only I need a regexp not only for character-to-character but for a second occurance of a character till a character.
My purpose is to get password from uri, example:

```
http://mylogin:mypassword@mywebpage.com
```

So in fact I need space from the second ":" till "@".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give the following regex a go:

`(?<=:)[^:]+?(?=@)`

It matches any consecutive string not containing any `:` character, prefixed by a `:` and suffixed by a `@`.

Depending on your flavour of regex you might need something like:

`:([^:]+?)@`

Which doesn't use lookarounds, this includes the `:` and `@` in the match, but the password will be in the first capturing group.

The `?` makes it lazy in case there should be any `@` characters in the actual url string, and as such it is optional. Please note that that this will match **any** character between `:` and `@` even newlines and so on.

Comment: i used your solution in my project and it works so far:D

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy one that does not need look-aheads or look-behinds:

```
.*:.*:([^@]+)@
```

Explanation:

- `.*:.*`: matches everything up to (and including) the second colon (`:`)
- `([^@]+)` matches the longest possible series of non-`@` characters
- `@` - matches the `@` character.

If you run this regex, the first capturing group (the expression between parentheses) will contain the password.

Here it is in action: http://regex101.com/r/fT6rI0