# Regex | Regular Expressions | Getting anything from start of character to second instance of different character

Tags: regex

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a regular expression to work, I want it to get everything starting from a character and ending on the second instance of another character.

```
Ex. "matchVersion":"6.22.165.3566" should result in = 6.22
```

I have tried an answer that rvalvik posted here , [regex match till a character from a second occurance of a different character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984723/regex-match-till-a-character-from-a-second-occurance-of-a-different-character) , but it only solves part of the problem as shown below.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIc38.jpg)

```
(?<=:")[^:]+?(?=")
```

I would like the expresion to do someting like this instead.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yALtM.jpg)

It have been trying to get everything after `:"` and before second occurance of `.`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try [`(?<=:")[^".]+\.[^".]+`](https://regex101.com/r/yDxJbf/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It have been trying to get everything after `:"` and before second occurance of `.`

You may use negated character class:

```
(?<=:")[^".]+\.[^".]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yDxJbf/1)

- `(?<=:")`  - asserts that there is a `:"` before the current position
- `[^".]+` - 1+ chars other than `.` and `"`
- `\.` - a dot
- `[^".]+` - 1+ chars other than `.` and `"`