# How do you get the substring using 2 encapsulating characters?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsrange

How do we get a substring from :

```
NSString *string = @"exmple string [image]";
```

where we want to extract the string in between "[" and "]".

I was thinking of using NSRange with:

```
NSRange rangeStart = [title rangeOfString:@"[" options:NSLiteralSearch];
NSRange rangeEnd = [title rangeOfString:@"]" options:NSLiteralSearch];
```

But i can't seem to find a solution on this.

Comment: That's the right start. Use the result of the two ranges to get the substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant 1:

```
NSRange rangeStart = [title rangeOfString:@"[" options:NSLiteralSearch];
NSRange rangeEnd = [title rangeOfString:@"]" options:NSLiteralSearch];
substring = [your_string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(rangeStart.location + 1, rangeEnd.location - rangeStart.location - 1)];
```

Variant 2:

```
NSArray *ar = componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[]"];
substring = ar[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclu) will give you the regular expression you want.

Answer (score 0):

Usage fo regular expression (**Regex**) is the way to go for this type of thing:

```
NSError* error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\[(.*?)\\]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSString *str = @"example string [image]";
NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
NSString *substringForFirstMatch;
if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
        substringForFirstMatch = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(rangeOfFirstMatch.location + 1, rangeOfFirstMatch.length - 2)];
  }

NSLog(@"%@", substringForFirstMatch); // will print image
```