# Extract string from between group of backsplash and double quote

Tags: regex, double-quotes

I want to get string from between \" using regular expression.

**Input** : "gram:\"who is $t34he\""

**Expected Ouput** : who is $t34he

I tried `/\\"(.*?)\\"/g` this and got `\"who is $t34he\"` but I don't need `\"` into the output string. Any solution.

Tried on http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: You can use: `/(?<=\\")(.*?)(?=\\")/g ` or use `group(1)` in your regex

Comment: which language are you running? print the group index 1.

Comment: refer to 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclu

Comment: What's the expected output of `"gram:\\"who is $t34he\\""` ? Or do you assume this can be parsed using double quote/escape standards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use looakaheads/behinds if supported

```
(?<=\\").*?(?=\\")
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/mJ3qB6/1)

Anyway, if not supported, just use `\\"(.*?)\\"` and take Group 1.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt at an answer (please bear with me if if there are slight errors!):

Using your site I got it to work with

```
[\w\s]*\$[\w]*
```

(where \w matches alphanumerical characters and \s whitespace)

That matches any dollar sign with alphanumerical+whitespace characters before it and alphanumerical chars after... so it starts and stops the match neatly between the quotes and backslashes. Am happy to make it more general if given more info on what expected inputs are. I hope the answer is constructive!

Comment: edit notes: answered completely irrelevantly the first time... new to all this!