# How do I match a string between characters in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match just the characters *between* some set characters using regex? I'm very new to this but I'm getting somewhere...

I want to match all instances of text between '[[' and ']]' in the following string:

'Hello, my [[name]] is [[Joffrey]]'.

So far I've been able to retrieve `[[name` and `[[Joffrey` with the following regex:

```
\[\[([^\]])*\g
```

I've experimented with grouping etc but can't seem to get the 'contents' only (`name` and `Joffrey`).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: [`\[\[(.*?)\]\]`](https://regex101.com/r/uJ7mG0/1)

Comment: show us the js code that you have used

Comment: `\[\[([^\]])*\g` ==> `/pattern/g`

Comment: @Tushar I guess you can add this as an answer

Comment: OP, `\[\[(.+?)\]\]` use this. @Tushar yours will match `[[]]` this with an empty string. isn't it?

Comment: Possible Dup/Close to dupe of [Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Yes, but [`\[\[(.+?)\]\]`](https://regex101.com/r/uJ7mG0/2) will match ``]] is [[Joffrey``.

Comment: What if a string has triple brackets that should not be accounted for? Like `'Hello, my my [[name]] is [[[Joffrey]]]'`?

Comment: @Tushar Thanks. I just started to learn it. why `.+?` caused greediness there even if i used `?`. ?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy It'll first match a single char and then try to being lazy whereas `*` will be lazy from the 0th index itself.

Comment: @Tushar I learnt a new technique in regex from you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var regex = /\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g;
var input = 'Hello, my my [[name]] is [[Joffrey]]';
var match;

do {
    match = regex.exec(input);
    if (match) {
        console.log(match[1]);
    }
} while (match);
```

Will print both matches in your console. Depending on whether you want to print out even blank values you would want to replace the "*" with a "+" `/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g`.

Comment: As far as I can see, other answers all return [[name]] and [[Joffrey]], not name and Joffrey. Thank you! Only problem is that three values are returned, the last undefined?

Comment: i can't reproduce the `undefined` problem. If you're executing this in your browser console there might be a `null` or `undefined` at the end because you don't return a value or something. If you just type `input` for example at the end this is removed and you get the input string. But that's not a problem that should occur in a productive webpage. I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex:

```
/\[\[(.*?)\]]/g
```

**Explanation**:

```
\[ Escaped character. Matches a "[" character (char code 91).

( Groups multiple tokens together and creates a capture group for extracting a substring or using a backreference.

. Dot. Matches any character except line breaks.
* Star. Match 0 or more of the preceding token.
? Lazy. Makes the preceding quantifier lazy, causing it to match as few characters as possible.
)
\] Escaped character. Matches a "]" character (char code 93).
] Character. Matches a "]" character (char code 93).
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `/\[\[(\w+)\]\]/g`

Demo in regex101 https://regex101.com/r/xX1pP0/1

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'Hello, my [[name]] is [[Joffrey]]';
var a = str.match(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g);
```