# C# find all strings between two characters inside word document

Tags: c#, search, replace, find, docx

I'm using DocX library to replace text inside word document. I want to somehow find all strings between "[]" inside my template docx file, for example [Name], [LastName], [Date] etc... and replace it with values which I previously load to datagridview which have same column name(Name, LastName, Date). Here is what I have so far:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in list)
{
    try
    {
        string template = txtUcitajTemplate.Text;
        string text2 = "Aneksi";
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(text2))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(text2);
        }
        string path = string.Format("{0}.docx", dataGridViewRow.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString());
        string path2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(text2, path);

        using (DocX document = DocX.Load(template))
        {
            string patternstart = Regex.Escape("[");
            string patternend = Regex.Escape("]");
            string regexexpr = patternstart + @"(.*?)" + patternend;
            // document.ReplaceText(regexexpr, dataGridViewRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            // document.ReplaceText(regexexpr, dataGridViewRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            var regex = new regex("[.*?]");
            var matches = regex.matches(input); //your matches: name, name@gmail.com
            foreach (var match in matches) // e.g. you can loop through your matches like this
            {
                document.ReplaceText(match.ToString(), dataGridViewRow.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString());
                document.ReplaceText(match.ToString(), dataGridViewRow.Cells["LastName"].Value.ToString());
            }
            document.SaveAs(path2);                     
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the question? Any error? Problem? Unexpected results?

Comment: Sorry, im not sure what should I put in regex.matches(input), to search through hole document and all find strings between []

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your regular expression, it looks like this question here is basically doing the same thing you are trying to (with regards to finding the values between two characters).

[Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)

If you use that premise then iterate through all matches. I suspect you will be able to alter your code to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: what should be my input for searching, inside Regex.Matches(input)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
var regex = new regex("[.*?]");
```

[See your RegEx here](https://regex101.com/r/jO4rW0/1)

You are matching any of the characters you have put between the brackets `[]`, meaning your RegEx will only match the characters `.`, `*` and `?` literally.

What you need to do is to escape these brackets:

```
\[.*?\]
```

[See it working here](https://regex101.com/r/qT6vH0/1)