# Find a string between two characters with grep

Tags: grep

I have found on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1454936/2068595) the regex to find a string between two characters. In my case I want to find every pattern between `‘` and `’`. Here's the regex :

```
(?<=‘)(.*?)(?=’)
```

Indeed, it works when I try it on https://regex101.com/.

The thing is I want to use it with `grep` but it doesn't work :

```
grep -E '(?<=‘)(.*?)(?=’)' file
```

Is there anything missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are positive look-ahead and look behind assertions. You need to enable it using PCRE(Perl Compatible Regex) and perhaps its better to get only matching part using `-o` option in GNU `grep`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=‘)(.*?)(?=’)' file
```