# How to get a value from a string that's between two delimiters, then set another value to what comes after the delimiters?

Tags: python

So lets say I have a string come in like this:

```
newData = "[Fruit]Apple"
```

How would I set set these variables from the string that was sent in?

```
type = "Fruit"
food = "Apple"
```

Comment: Seems rather trivial... What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: `m = re.match(r'\[(?P<type>w+)\](?P<name>\w+)', "[Fruit]Apple"); type =m.group('type'); food = m.group('name')`?

Comment: What is there's nesting?

Comment: @Bakuriu the regex version is actually [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud) which also means this is a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` and `split`:

```
type, food = newData.replace('[','').split(']')
```

Or without `replace` (credit @Bakuriu), with *slicing*:

```
type, food = newData[1:].split(']')
```

Comment: I don't really see the value of using `replace` here. The format is so fixed that it's probably better to just do `newData[1:].split(']')`. If the format gets more complicated the `replace` wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: @Bakuriu I thought of that too, but I can't be sure of how `[1:]` plays out in a general case either, say when `[` is not at the start of the string.

Comment: If `[` is not at the start your solution fails too, because you obtain `type = " Fruit"` (with initial space) instead of `"Fruit"` which may be significant if that string is used to lookup something etc.

Comment: @Bakuriu `replace` would not leave a leading space if `[` is not at the start

Comment: Yes it does: the leading space before the `[` ends up into the `type`:  `>>> '    [a]b'.replace('[', '').split(']') -->['    a', 'b']`.  Sure, you could `lstrip` the data before but at that point again you could just do `newData.lstrip()[1:]`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Seems there's a misunderstanding. OP's question has no leading space.

Comment: *You* were the one that bring to my attention the possibility of `[` not being at the start. My whole point is: if the format is there is always a single `[` at the start of the string, then `[1:]` is just simpler and better. If `[` might not be at the start your solution wont work correctly anyway without some adjustment. So, either you go on and generalize it a bit moreto handled such cases, or you are just suggesting a complicated way of doing `[1:]`. I hope to have been clear now.

Comment: @Bakuriu Ah that! I get the point the point now. I will add the `[1:]` version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()`

```
food = newData.split(']')[-1]
type = newData.split(']')[0].split('[')[-1]
```