# How to extract text in square brackets from string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I extract the text between all pairs of square brackets from the a string **`"[a][b][c][d][e]"`**, so that I can get the following results:

→ **Array: `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]`**

→ **String: `"abcde"`**

I have tried the following **`Regular Expressions`**, but to no avail:

→ **`(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])`**

→ **`\[(.*?)\]`**

Comment: Show us the code you used to apply these regular expressions.

Comment: Your first regex fails because javascript does not allow lookbehind, your second regex _may_ work with global flag but you would need to map the array to take rid off initial `[` and ending `]` characters.

Comment: If you are confident that the strings are always between matched pairs of square brackets, then `('[a][b][c][d][e]'.match(/[^\[\]]+/g) || []).join('')` should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Research:**

After having searched in Stack Overflow, I have only found two solutions, both of which using **`Regular Expressions`** and they can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1454936/6313073):

→ **`(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])`** **<sup>(1)</sup>**

1. **`(?<=\[)`** : Positive Lookbehind.
2. **`\[`** :matches the character **`[`** literally.
3. **`(.*?)`** : matches any character except newline and expands as needed.
4. **`(?=\])`** :  Positive Lookahead.
5. **`\]`** : matches the character **`]`** literally.

→ **`\[(.*?)\]`** **<sup>(2)</sup>**

1. **`\[`** : matches the character **`[`** literally.
2. **`(.*?)`** : matches any character except newline and expands as needed.
3. **`\]`** : matches the character **`]`** literally.

---

### **Notes:**

**<sup>(1)</sup>** This pattern throws an error in **`JavaScript`**, because the lookbehind operator is not supported.

**Example:**

```
console.log(/(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])/.exec("[a][b][c][d][e]"));

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])/: Invalid group(…)
```

**<sup>(2)</sup>** This pattern returns the text inside only the first pair of square brackets as the second element.

**Example:**

```
console.log(/\[(.*?)\]/.exec("[a][b][c][d][e]"));

Returns: ["[a]", "a"]
```

---

### **Solution:**

The most precise solution for **`JavaScript`** that I have come up with is:

```
var string, array;

string = "[a][b][c][d][e]";
array = string.split("[");    // → ["", "a]", "b]", "c]", "d]", "e]"]
string = array1.join("");     // → "a]b]c]d]e]"
array = string.split("]");    // → ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", ""]
```

Now, depending upon whether we want the end result to be an array or a string we can do:

```
array = array.slice(0, array.length - 1)     // → ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
/* OR */
string = array.join("")                      // → "abcde"
```

---

### **One liner:**

Finally, here's a handy one liner for each scenario for people like me who prefer to achieve the most with least code or our **`TL;DR`** guys.

**Array:**

```
var a = "[a][b][c][d][e]".split("[").join("").split("]").slice(0,-1);
/* OR */
var a = "[a][b][c][d][e]".slice(1,-1).split(']['); // Thanks @xorspark
```

**String:**

```
var a = "[a][b][c][d][e]".split("[").join("").split("]").join("");
```

Comment: A RE would probably be more efficient though.

Comment: You can save the extra split by just slicing off the first and last square brackets and split on "][" instead:  `"[a][b][c][d][e]".slice(1,-1).split('][');`

Comment: Nice solution @xorspark!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what text you are expecting in that string of array, but for the example you've given.

```
var arrStr = "[a][b][c][d][e]";
var arr = arrStr.match(/[a-z]/g) --> [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ] with typeof 'array'

then you can just use `.concat()` on the produced array to combine them into a string.
```

if you're expecting multiple characters between the square brackets, then the regex can be `(/[a-z]+/g)` or tweaked to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach will be interesting to you.

```js
    var arr = [];
    var str = '';
    var input = "[a][b][c][d][e]";
    input.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, function(match, pattern){
      arr.push(pattern);
      str += pattern;
      return match;//just in case ;)
    });
    
    console.log('Arr:', arr);
    console.log('String:', str);

//And trivial solution if you need only string
var a = input.replace(/\[|\]/g, '');
console.log('Trivial:',a);
```