# Match a string between two characters regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to use `new RegExp`
I need to get a match if there is a specific string between two characters, but no match if that is a similar string between those characters, `/` and `?`.
I.e:

String to match is:

`"https://www.mysite.se/should-match?ba=11"`

And I have `should-ma`

That should `not` give any match. But `should-match` should give a match
So I need to create `new RegExp()`

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud

Comment: That's for PHP, but you should be able to use the regex within JavaScript as well.  There are multiple sites that will let you test this as well.  https://regex101.com/

Comment: @adpro Ok, thanks. but how to match specific text between `/` and `?` ?

Comment: \/(.*?)\? - that's fairly close - I'm sure you can take it from there. This would give you '/www.mysite.se/should-match', so you'll have to refine a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?!\/)[^\/\?]*(?=\?)
```

[(test it out)](https://regex101.com/r/Ww3akq/1)

Replace `\/` with the start delimiter and `\?` with the end delimiter. If the start or end delimiters have any of `.?*+^$[]\(){}|-` in them, you will need to add a `\` before them, or use this function to do the work for you:

```
var escape = function(str) {
    return (str+'').replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&");
};
```

Alternative:

```
var matcher = function(str, start, end){
    var quote = function(str) {
        return (str+'').replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&");
    };
    return str.match(new RegExp(quote(start) + "[^" + quote(start) + quote(end) + "]*" + quote(end)))[0].slice(1, -1)
};
```

Use like `matcher("https://www.mysite.se/should-match?ba=11", "/", "?")`.

Comment: Thanks but I only need what to put inside `new RegExp`. Please answer that and I accept :)

Comment: @user1665355 fixed.

Comment: The problem is still that I use it in mongo and I have a string already, say ``should-ma` and I only must have `new Regexp`. I.e. `MyField: new RegExp(...)`

Comment: @user1665355 does `(?!\/)[^\/\?]*(?=\?)` not work for you?

Comment: it works but I `need` to put my own word, not match what is between `/` and `?`. Do you understand? :)

Comment: @user1665355 What characters do you need to match between?

Comment: between `/` and `?`. So new RegExp(should-ma) should not match but new RegExp(should-match) should match. It is a mongodb field I work with. So I `must put a variable inside new RegExp`, between `/` and `?`

Comment: No, because it needs to match exactly. So even if `should-ma` is contained in `should-match`, it should not match. So no match if it contains.I.e. the string between `/` and `?` should be exact.

Comment: @user1665355 what about `\/should-match\?`?

Comment: No the pattern between / and ? MUST be exactly what I put in. So "should-ma" should not match www.mysite.com/should-match?. Now it does. Basically pattern can not be contained in pattern in my url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145972/discussion-between-programmer5000-and-user1665355).