# Match specific string anywhere between characters

Tags: regex

I'm not looking to match *everything* between two characters, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud). I'm looking to match a specific phrase. For example:

```
cat {mouse ostrich dog ostrich} fish {ostrich} ostrich
```

I want to match the three 'ostrich' strings in the curly brackets, but not anything else. Is that possible?

Comment: Please show what you have done so far and where it fails.

Answer (score -2):

If your engine supports `\G` (PCRE, ...) you could very well get along with

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|{) # match the start of the last match or {
[^{}]*?\K      # not { or } lazily, \K "forgets" the match thus far
ostrich        # ostrich literally
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/XlofUT/1).