# Regex match after @ but not include and before / but not include

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a regex noob and I try this for a long time.

```
case1: postgres://123:123@localhost/123
case2: postgres://123:123@integration/123
```

I am trying to find a regex that matches after `@` and before `/`

For case 1 will give me localhost, case 2 will give me integration

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud

Comment: If you have tried this for a long time, you certainly have something to show that you've tried, right?

Comment: so this (?=\@)(.*?)(?=\/) gave me @localhost which still include @. I also have tried (?:\@)(.*?)(?=\/) and got the same result.

Comment: Try `.*@\K.*(?=\/)`

Comment: Tip: If you don't get it to work with regex, think if you can use something else.  In this case, splitting on `@` and then on `/` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Just process the match to remove the delimiter(s). There is not much else you can do since JavaScript regex doesn't support lookahead. This should do it.

```js
var strs = ["postgres://123:123@localhost/123", "postgres://123:123@integration/123"];
strs.forEach(str => console.log(str.match(/(?=@)[^\/]+/)[0].substr(1)));
```

What this does is to return a match that includes the `@` and then process that match to remove the delimiter.

You may want to check if there are any matches before you do this to avoid exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test = [
    'postgres://123:123@localhost/123',
    'postgres://123:123@integration/123'
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a.match(/@(\w+)/)[1];
}));
```