# Regex match string between two characters

Tags: regex

Let's say I have a string containing a filename that includes width and height.. 
eg.

> "en/text/org-affiliate-250x450.en.gif"

how can I get only the "250" contained by '-' and 'x' and then the "450" containd by 'x' and '.' using regex?

I tried following this answer but with no luck.
[Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)

Comment: Please show your effort.

Comment: @Utkanos I tried following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookbehind and a lookahead:

```
(?<=-|x)\d+(?=x|\.)
```

- `(?<=-|x)` Lookbehind for either a `-` or a `x`.
- `\d+` Match digits.
- `(?=x|\.)` Lookahead for either a `x` or a `.`.

Try the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/h0InSN/1).

Comment: worked like a charm... thanks for the explanation too.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using R then you can try following solution

```
txt = "en/text/org-affiliate-250x450.en.gif"
x <- gregexpr("[0-9]+", txt) 
x2 <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(txt, x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex `-(\d)+x(\d+)\.`:

```js
var str = 'en/text/org-affiliate-250x450.en.gif';
var numbers = /-(\d+)x(\d+)\./.exec(str);
numbers = [parseInt(numbers[1]), parseInt(numbers[2])];
console.log(numbers);
```