# Regular Expression Match between occurrence of character

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I have the following string:

```
3#White House, District Of Columbia, United States#US#USDC#DC001#38.8951#-77.0364#531871#382
```

as you can see, the string is delimited by #'s. My use-case resembles a simple SPLIT(string,"#") operation but regex gives me a bit more flexibility.

I would like to match the characters between two occurrences of #'s. for example the characters between the second and third occurrence should match: 'US'

I'm using Google Bigquery and was able to match the first two terms of the string but struggle with the third:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(locations,r'^\d') as location_type,    
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(locations,r'^\d#.*?#'),r'^\d*#|#','') as location_full_name, 
????
```

locations are strings such as the one above.

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud#1454936) but I have multiple delimeters and would like to specify between which occurences the match should take place e.g. 2 and 5th occurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a regex like `^(?:[^#]*#){N}([^#]*)` where `N` is the number of your required substring minus 1. To get `US`, which is the third value, you may use

```
^(?:[^#]*#){2}([^#]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G5J5wg/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^#]*#){2}` - two sequences of

  - `[^#]*` - any zero or more chars other than `#`
  - `#` - a `#` char
- `([^#]*)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than `#`.

Comment: wow, this is very powerful. How would you, using this regex, match between the 2nd and 5th occurrence? Can probably figure out the rest myself.

Comment: @RutgerHofste If you want to match them inclusively, [`^(?:[^#]*#)([^#]*(?:#[^#]*){3})`](https://regex101.com/r/G5J5wg/2)

Comment: The expected result would be "US#USDC#DC001#38.8951" (all characters including delimiter between the 2nd and 5th occurrence of the delimiter)

Comment: @RutgerHofste Then use `{2}` limiting quantifier after the non-capturing group, [`^(?:[^#]*#){2}([^#]*(?:#[^#]*){3})`](https://regex101.com/r/G5J5wg/3)

Answer (score 1):

> My use-case resembles a simple SPLIT(string,"#") operation but regex gives me a bit more flexibility

Obviously `REGEXP_EXTRACT()` is the way to go here - but wanted to throw different option to show flexibility in using split too - just one of an option

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '3#White House, District Of Columbia, United States#US#USDC#DC001#38.8951#-77.0364#531871#382' locations
)
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(locations, r'^(?:[^#]*#){2}([^#]*(?:#[^#]*){3})') value_via_regexp,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(part, '#' ORDER BY pos) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(locations, '#')) part WITH OFFSET pos WHERE pos BETWEEN 2 AND 5) value_via_split_unnest
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result as

```
Row     value_via_regexp            value_via_split_unnest   
1       US#USDC#DC001#38.8951       US#USDC#DC001#38.8951
```

Comment: Hi i had something of a similar conundrum. I am using a BQ query and my dataset has the info in 1 of the columns like
record 1 : "A.B.C.D"
Record 2 : "P.Q.R"
Record 3 : "X.Y"
Record 4 : "L.M.N"
and i have to get the values except the dots in separate columns. Note that there cud be varying number of dots inside 1 column. Struggling with this to do it in 1 shot in a query.