# How apply text effects to a word inside { } curly braces

Tags: java, android, regex, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have text that comes from SQLite database to my onBindViewHolder in this form: **Hello I am {Alex}**.
I want to be able to adjust size or colour of the text inside **{}** and hide those **{}** curly braces from output. So final desire to have text like this: Hello I am **Alex**

For the first time I meet with Regex related thing, can anybody give me short step by step guide how to accomplish this.

I found similar question:

[Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)

But I do not understand how should I handle "**(?<=[)(.*?)(?=])**" in my case.

Now my onBindViewHolder looks like this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Question question = questionList.get(position);
    holder.tvQuestion.setText(question.getQuestion());
//  holder.tvQuestion.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0099cc"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not good with regular expression. But here is an answer to your question that will let you get the desired result (get the expression text and format it accordingly).

```
public CharSequence getFormattedQuestion(Context context, String originalQues, @ColorRes int colorToSet, @DimenRes int textSize) {

    // First we check if the question has the expression
    if (originalQues == null || !originalQues.contains("{") || !originalQues.contains("}")) {
        return originalQues;
    }

    // Then we break the original text into parts

    int startIndex = originalQues.indexOf("{");
    int endIndex = originalQues.indexOf("}");

    // 1) The text before the expression
    String leftPart = startIndex>0 ? originalQues.substring(0, startIndex) : "";

    // 2) The text after the expression (if there is any)
    String rightPart = endIndex == originalQues.length()-1 ? "" : originalQues.substring(endIndex+1);

    // 3) The expression text
    String midPart = originalQues.substring(startIndex+1, endIndex);

    // 4) Format the mid part with the give color (colorToSet) and size (textSize)
    SpannableString spannableMid = new SpannableString(midPart);
    spannableMid.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorToSet)), 0, midPart.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableMid.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(textSize)), 0, midPart.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);


    // check if there is any left part; if so, add it with mid
    CharSequence leftAndMid = leftPart.length()>0 ? TextUtils.concat(leftPart, " ", spannableMid) : spannableMid;

    // Check if there is any right part else return the left and mid
    return rightPart.length()>0 ? TextUtils.concat(leftAndMid, " ", rightPart) : leftAndMid;
}
```

So basically we are Splitting the original question into 3 parts. Part one, the text before expression. Part 2 the expression text. Part 3 the text after the expression. Then we format the expression text(Part2) with color and size using `SpannableString`. Then we return a new text by combining all three.
You can then use it like this

```
CharSequence ques = getFormattedQuestion(holder.itemView.getContext(), question.getQuestion(), R.color.blue, R.dimen.text_size);
holder.tvQuestion.setText(ques);
```

Comment: @AlexK My bad. The issue was with the `leftPart`. I have updated the code. Please check now.

Comment: sidhnarth jain, Thank you very much. It makes effect. Now text in recycle view looks like this "Alex}.Alex". Something wrong with part before the "{" it doesn't show anymore. I need to understand your code better.  I will write update later.

Comment: @AlexK did you try the updated method? Still not working?

Comment: @AlexK I have added some explanation. Now you will be able to understand it better. There are comments that describe each step.

Comment: Great Man! It is working. As beginner now I am trying to understand the part where you work with the string. Those -1 and +1 confusing me.

Comment: Haha! Good, try to clear that by yourself that will help you in long run. If still have any doubts, let me know.