# regex expression to Delete part of a string between two tags

Tags: regex

Suppose I've got a string like:

```
"Hello this something <tag=blah blah>some more text here doesnt matter </tag>else"
```

How would I go about obtaining the following text from the given string:

"Hello this something else"

Right now I've ended up with this regex expression:

```
(?<=<tag)(.*)(?=<\/tag>)
```

but it doesnt work. Help?

Comment: Oops, forgot to put it in a code block

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What is the current result?

Comment: I get no matches in my string

Comment: Similar question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)

Comment: I just tested it and it's matching just fine, have you tested it on https://regex101.com/ ?

Comment: As I said in the answer, @FjsodonfDheos, removing the lookahead and lookbehind parts should make it work as you describe. Also, maybe that's the problem. Depending on the flavor, lookahead and lookbehinds might not be supported

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/XTQnDX/1)

Comment: Visual studio code says your regular expression"`(?<=<tag)(.*)(?=<\/tag>)`" is invalid.

Please try this "`<tag.*</tag>"`

Answer (score 1):

`(.*)<tag.*<\/tag>(.*)`

This will allow you to combine the first and second capture group into the string you are looking for.

If however you are after **replacing** ("deleting") the middle part, you could use this pattern:

`<tag.*?\/tag>`

The string you are after would then remain.

https://regex101.com/ is indeed a very nice environment to try out patterns and analyse them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you also want to delete the tags, they should **not** be in look-ahead and look-behind.

If you want to match the part you want to delete, I would simply use:

```
<tag(.*)<\/tag>
```

Also, that might be why it doesn't return any result, since depending on the flavor, lookahead and lookbehinds might not be supported.

However, if you want to get the text around, you can use:

```
(.*)<tag.*<\/tag>(.*)
```

and you will have the text in groups 1 and 2.

Comment: The question is how to get the text that is wrapped around the tags, not what is inside of them.

Comment: He specifically asks a regex to *delete*, so I assume he wants to match the part he wants to delete, like when you do `string.replace(regex, '')` or similar. Anyway, you are right, gonna specify it on the answer

Comment: I agree the question is a bit vague on matching and/or replacing.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `Regex.Replace`. Here is a c# example:

```
string input = "Hello this something <tag=blah blah>some more text here doesnt matter </tag>else";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, @"<tag.*?\/tag>", string.Empty)
```

Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2) to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

A solution in R:

```
test <- "Hello this something <tag=blah blah>some more text here doesnt matter </tag>else"
# use function gsub(): 
gsub("<tag.*?/tag.*?>", "", test, perl=T) 
[1] "Hello this something else"
```

Comment: I don't think that that is a universal regex pattern...