# Problem to identify string between a regular expression

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the string between the symbols of a Regular Expression, but it seems to found nothing in the TextBox

```
var ph = txtCodigo.Text;
     foreach(Match m in 
         Regex.Matches(ph,@"${(.*?)}$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
     {
         lstParams.Items.Add(m.Groups[1].ToString());
     }
```

I expect the string betwwen this symbols ${  }$, but the actual output is nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)

Comment: `$` is a special symbol in regex; it signifies the end of the string. Escape it to search for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` is a special symbol in regexes, so much like special symbols in other places is must be escaped `\$`. To get something inside a tag but while excluding the tags, we use something in regex called a `lookaround` expression.

```
Regex rx = "(?<=\$\{).+?(?=\}\$)"
```

Explanation

`(?<=` find and exclude starting symbols, in this case `${`. Technical name is `positive lookbehind`

`.+?`  find any number of characters (special, whitespace, or otherwise)

`(?=`  find and exclude closing symbols, in this case `}$`. Technical name is `positive lookahead`

[Example on Regexr](https://regexr.com/4d43t)  Test your regexes out on Regexr, it will save you a lot of headaches

Comment: This one worked for me  very well, thanks a lot, but now I have another problem, I have to now identify the name of the image (logo,jpg) in another regular expression, I have my image tags like this <img class="" src="logo.jpg"> and the regular expression that I got in regex101.com is \<img class="(.*?)" src="(.*?)" \/> but it seems to return nothing again, help please =(

Comment: Try this `(?<=<img class="" src=").+?(?=">$)`