# Regular expression that matches when a character is in between two characters, but the inner character can be one of the outer delimiters

Tags: regex, url, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, iri

I have a string like this:

```
<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>
```

and I want a Regex that will match whenever there's a situation like this:

```
<https://example.com/code/INSTRUMENTS/AGD<1>
<https://example.com/code/INSTRUMENTS/AGD>1>
```

to detect such invalidly serialized IRIs (similar to URIs/URLs).

I've looked at [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud) [answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249444/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-two-strings-where-the-last-string-can) on SO, but none of them seem to work when the inner character is the same as one of the outer characters.

Comment: We would need to see the context of these tags in a larger text, but in any case, you would probably need a balanced parser to handle this in general.

Answer (score 0):

Given the assumption that `<` always has to be closed with a `>` and they cannot be "nested":

`(<[^>]*<|>[^<]*>)`

This will detect them if its just about boolean checking/validation.

If you also want to capture the full string

`(<[^>]*<[^<]*>|<[^>]*>[^<]*>)`

*(I hope I don't have a typo)*