# Extract specific text surrounded by white space

Tags: regex

I have written some basic regex:

```
/[0123BCDER]/g
```

I would like to extract the bold numbers from the below lines. The regex i have written extracts the character however i would only like to extract the character if it is surrounded by white space. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 721658A220421EE5867            AMBER YUR DE STE 30367887462580                  **1**                                                        00355132

 172638A220421ER3028            NIKITA YUAN         318058763400580                  **1**                                                        00355133

 982658A230421MC1234            SEAN D W MC100050420965155230421            **3**                  14032887609303                        00355134
```

Please note the character or digit will always be by itself.

Comment: Are those always 1 digit numbers?

Comment: `(?<=\s)[0123BCDER](?=\s)` or `\s([0123BCDER])\s`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)

Comment: `/\b\d\b/g` would do it

Comment: @MonkeyZeus OP explicitly said "whitespace" though. If they meant that literally, `\b` might include false positives.

Comment: @ulou yes always one digit numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loking for something like this: `/\s\d\s/g`.

- `\s` - match whitespace,
- `\d` - match any digit,
- `/g` - match all occurrences.

You can also replace `\d` with e.g. `[0123BCDER]` (your example) or `[0-9A-Za-z]` (all alphanumberic).

```js
const input = `721658A220421EE5867            AMBER YUR DE STE 30367887462580                  1                                                       00355132

 172638A220421ER3028            NIKITA YUAN         318058763400580                  1                                                        00355133      _

 982658A230421MC1234            SEAN D W MC100050420965155230421            3                  14032887609303                        00355134
`

// with whitespaces
const res = input.match(/\s\d\s/g)
console.log(res)

// alphanumeric 
const res2 = input.match(/\s[A-Za-z0-9]\s/g)
console.log(res2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this works if a digit is surrounded by white space however for instances where it is not a digit and one of the following characters this does not work [BCDER] the character will always be 1 digit/character long if that helps

Comment: Just replace `\d` with `[0123BCDER]` or whatever character you want.