# Python regex expression between variable strings and content check between

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

I would like to find all the strings that appear between an element of a list `start_signs`
and `end_signs`. When the element in `end_signs` is missing or appearing of context later,
the solution should not be taken.

One solution would be to take all the matches between `start_signs` and `end_signs`
and check, wether the matches contain only words from a third list `allowed_words_between`.

```
import re

allowed_words_between = ["and","with","a","very","beautiful"]

start_signs           = ["$","$$"]
end_signs             = ["Ferrari","BMW","Lamborghini","ship"]

teststring = """
             I would like to be a $-millionaire with a Ferrari.                                     -> Match: $-millionaire with a Ferrari
             I would like to be a $$-millionair with a Lamborghini.                                 -> Match: $$-millionair with a Lamborghini
             I would like to be a $$-millionair with a rotten Lamborghini.                          -> No Match because of the word "rotten"
             I would like to be a $$-millionair with a Lamborghini and a Ferrari.                   -> Match: $$-millionair with a Lamborghini and a Ferrari
             I would like to be a $-millionaire with a very, very beautiful ship!                   -> Match: $-millionaire with a very, very beautiful ship
             I would like to be a $-millionaire with a very, very beautiful but a bit dirty ship.                       -> No Match because of the word dirty
             I would like to be a $-millionaire with a dog, a cat, two children and a cowboy hat. That would be great.   -> No Match
             """
```

Another solution would be to start the string with the `start_signs` and cut it as soon as a string not appearing in an allowed list appears:

```
allowed_list = allowed_words_between + start_signs + end_signs
```

---

What I tried so far:

I used the solution of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)

```
regexString = "("+"|".join(start_signs) + ")" + ".*?" + "(" +"|".join(end_signs)+")"
```

and tried to create a regex string that is variable w.r.t. start and end. That is not not working.
I also don't know how the content check could work.

```
matches          = re.findall(regexString,teststring)
substituted_text = re.sub(regexString, "[[Found It]]", teststring, count=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat all the `allowed_words_between` optionally followed by a comma and whitespace chars until you reach one of the `end_signs`.

You can turn the capture groups into non capturing `(?:` or else re.findall will return the capture group values.

Note to escape the `\$` to match it literally

The pattern will look like

```
(?:\$|\$\$)\S*(?:(?:\s+(?:and|with|a|very|beautiful),?)*\s+(?:Ferrari|BMW|Lamborghini|ship))+
```

The pattern matches

- `(?:\$|\$\$)\S*` Match any of the **start_signs** followed by optional non whitespace chars (`\S` can also match a dollar sign, but you can make that more specific like `-\w+`)
- `(?:` Outer non capture group

  - `(?:` Inner non capture group

    - `\s+(?:and|with|a|very|beautiful),?` Match any of the **allowed_words_between** optionally followed by a comma
  - `)*\s+` Close inner non capture group and repeat 0+ times followed by 1+ whitspace chars
  - `(?:Ferrari|BMW|Lamborghini|ship)` Match any of the **end_signs**
- `)+` Close outer non capture group and repeat 1+ times to also match the string with *Lamborghini and a Ferrari*

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9FveT8/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2UFMC0)

```
import re

allowed_words_between = ["and", "with", "a", "very", "beautiful"]
start_signs = [r"\$", "\$\$"]
end_signs = ["Ferrari", "BMW", "Lamborghini", "ship"]
teststring = """
             I would like to be a $-millionaire with a Ferrari.
             I would like to be a $$-millionair with a Lamborghini.
             I would like to be a $$-millionair with a rotten Lamborghini.
             I would like to be a $$-millionair with a Lamborghini and a Ferrari.
             I would like to be a $-millionaire with a very, very beautiful ship!
             I would like to be a $-millionaire with a very, very beautiful but a bit dirty ship.
             I would like to be a $-millionaire with a dog, a cat, two children and a cowboy hat. That would be great.
             """
regexString = "(?:" + "|".join(start_signs) + ")\S*(?:(?:\s+(?:" + "|".join(allowed_words_between) + "),?)*\s+(?:" + "|".join(end_signs) + "))+"

for s in re.findall(regexString, teststring):
    print(s)
```

Output

```
$-millionaire with a Ferrari
$$-millionair with a Lamborghini
$$-millionair with a Lamborghini and a Ferrari
$-millionaire with a very, very beautiful ship
```