# Pandas: How to split a column of string of multiple tuples to multiple columns of individual string of tuple

Tags: python, pandas

I need advice on how to proceed when slicing a string with an explanation.

I have in dataframe column:

| data |
| --- |
| (0,1), (1,2) |

And I would like to divide it into this form.

| 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- |
| (0,1) | (1,2) |

How to split this string correctly?

When I use this:

```
.str.split(',', expand=True)
```

, it also divides my string between parentheses, but I don't want to. How to do this correctly (and an explanation please)?

Comment: Added explanation on the solution using `str.split()`.   This solution is a tweak on your code, to ensure only split on the comma between tuples instead of within a tuple.

Comment: @SeaBean Yes you're right. For the solution, I had to tweak my data a bit to make it work. It's a fact that I was inquiring about a dataframe. I modified the solution label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex, as follows:

```
df['data'].str.extract(r'(\(\d+,\s*\d+\))\s*,\s*(\(\d+,\s*\d+\))')
```

or use [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), as follows:

```
df['data'].str.split(r'(?<=\))\s*,\s*', expand=True)
```

Here we use regex positive lookbehind to look for a closing parenthesis `)` before comma `,` for the comma to match.  Hence, we only split on the comma between tuples and not within tuples.

**Result:**

```
       0      1
0  (0,1)  (1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`.

```
tuple_str = "(0,1), (1,2)"
my_tuple = eval(tuple_str)
print(my_tuple)
>>> ((0, 1), (1, 2))
```

Read more about `eval` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"data":['(0,1), (1,2)']})

new_df=pd.DataFrame(df.data.str.split(", ").tolist())
print(new_df)
"""
           data
0  (0,1), (1,2)

       0      1
0  (0,1)  (1,2)
"""
```

We are splitting "data" column using `,`  , we converted that into list and we are making new `DataFarme` using that data.

Answer (score 1):

Also using regex as other anwser, but you can use re.split

```py
import re

str='(0,1), (1,2),(3,4)' 
re.split('(?<=\)) *, *(?=\()', str) #['(0,1)', '(1,2)', '(3,4)']
```

like `String.split`, `re.split` will split string but using regex as delimiter
`re.split` document can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split

regex I use come from this answer.
[Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)

Answer (score 1):

Use regex `\(\d+,\s*\d+\)` to match two comma separated numbers enclosed by parenthesis, pass this regex to `str.findall` then apply `pd.Series`. It will create new columns with the values that match the pattern.

```py
df['data'].str.findall('\(\d+,\s*\d+\)').apply(pd.Series)
       0      1
0  (0,1)  (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try regexs:

```
import re
r=re.findall(r'\(\d+,\d+\)','(0,1),(1,2)')
print(r) # ['(0,1)', '(1,2)']
```

`re.findall` means finding all strings matching the regex (first argument) within the haystack (second argument).

The regex given means to match a pair of `()` with two numbers (`\d+`) seperated by a `,`.

Or if you want a more extendable version,swap out the second line with
`r=re.findall(r'\(.*?\)','(0,1),(1,2)')`

The `.*?` means to match any number of charctors but try matching as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex with `Series.str.split`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['(0,1), (1,2)']})
df2 = df['data'].str.split(r'\s*,\s*(?![^()]*\))', expand=True)
```

Output of `df2`:

```
       0       1
0  (0,1)   (1,2)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hbQdf8/1). *Details*:

- `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(?![^()]*\))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char.