# Regex - Include only matches up to max length

Tags: python, regex

In this
[much upvoted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud) 12 years ago, it has been asked, how to extract the content of brackets e.g.

```
I want to find an answer on the internet [stackoverflow].
```

The wanted expression to extract the brackets and the content is

```
\[.*?\]                     # -> [stackoverflow]
```

while the

```
(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])    # -> stackoverflow
```

extracts the content only. I would like to match only those expression that are not longer than 10 characters.

My guess would something like

```
\[.*?\]{,100}
```

but that is not working. Where do I put the condition of the maximal length?

Comment: Do you mean 10 with `[` and `]`? `\[[^][]{0,8}]`? Or `\[[^][]{0,10}]` (12 with `[` and `]`)?

Comment: In the post, `100` would be the maximum length, with 0 being the minimum. This is clearly no `10`. Defining “not working” with relevant details is usually a productive start. (Python might require an explicit number before the comma in the **“interval quantifier”**; the syntax varies a bit.) Anyway, https://blog.finxter.com/python-regex-greedy-vs-non-greedy-quantifiers/ might be a handy read.

Comment: By "not working" I meant not matching in [online regex testing](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: more like `\[.{,10}\]`

Comment: Unfortunately, e.g. ```\[[^][]{0,1000}]``` or ```\[[^][]{0,10}]``` is not matching.