# Kotlin Regex to Extract after and before a specific character

Tags: string, kotlin

In Kotlin, i need to find the string value after and before of specific character,

For example,

```
Item1. myResultValue: someother string
```

So in the above, I need to get the value after ". " and before ":" SO my output should be "myResultValue". If it doesn't match it can return empty or null value.

Please help to write to Regex for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)

Comment: Can there be multiple such patterns in the string i.e. multiple `. ` or `:`? What output do you expect in that case? Just the first match or all of them?

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case you can use regex:

```
val text = "Item1. myResultValue: someother string"

val pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\.(.*):.*")
val matcher = pattern.matcher(text)
if (matcher.matches()) {
    println(matcher.group(1))
}
```

If you want to build something smarter that defines the start and end pattern you can do it like this:

```
val startSearch = "\\."
val endSearch = ":"
val text = "Item1. myResultValue: someother string"

val pattern = Pattern.compile(".*$startSearch(.*)$endSearch.*")
val matcher = pattern.matcher(text)
if (matcher.matches()) {
    println(matcher.group(1))
}
```