# Replace $..$ within a string with \(...\) in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string here 'Let $[C | d]$ be $Star$'.

How to replace $..$ within the above string with \(...\).

The result should be 'Let \([C | d]\) be \(Star\)'.

How can I do it python.

I have tried as

```
import re
x = 'Let $[C | d]$ be $Star$'
y = re.sub(r'\$.*?\$', r'\\(.*?\\)', x)
```

but not working.

the output was 'Let \(.*?\) be \(.*?\)'

Ref : [Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)

Comment: maybe `re.sub(r'\$(.*?)\$', r'\(\1\)', x)`?

Answer (score 0):

It should work, here is the working example.

```
import re

string = 'Let $[C | d]$ be $Star$'

result = re.sub(r'\$(.*?)\$', r'\\(\1\\)', string)

print(result)
```

Explanation **:**

`re.sub`: This is the function provided by the re module in Python for performing regular expression substitution.
`r'\$(.*?)\$'`: This is the regular expression pattern used for matching the desired pattern of `$..$` in the string.

- `\`: This is an escape character that ensures the following `$` symbols are treated as literal characters, not as special characters in the regular expression.
- `\$(.*?)\$`: This captures the content between the `$` symbols as a group. The `.*?` is a non-greedy match that captures any characters (except newline characters) between the `$` symbols, but as few as possible.

`r'(\1)'`: This is the replacement pattern for the matched pattern.

- `(\1)`: This uses a backreference to refer to the first captured group in the pattern. In this case, it refers to the content captured between the `$` symbols. By surrounding `\1` with parentheses, we specify that the replacement should have the format `(...)`, capturing the content of the first group.